# array assignment fails with a hyphen/dash in the data

Tags: ksh

I have a command, whose output is:

```
"-1/2"
"-B"
"A"
"C"
```

But, when I want to assign the command's output to an array, like:

```
temp=`command`
eval set -A array $temp
```

It told me:

```
./test.ksh[6]: -1/2: 0403-010 A specified flag is not valid for this command.
```

But if I remove the hyphens in the first two lines of input (with the help of `sed`), the array could be assigned without problem. What is the reason here? Is there any method to keep the hyphened data and assign them into the array as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try this in ksh93, I see

```
$ out='"-1/2"
"-B"
"A"
"C"'
$ echo "$out"
"-1/2"
"-B"
"A"
"C"
$ set -A ary $out 
$ echo "${ary[@]}"
"-1/2" "-B" "A" "C"
$ set -o vi
$ unset ary
$ eval set -A ary $out
ksh: eval[1]: set: -1: unknown option
ksh: eval[1]: set: -/: unknown option
ksh: eval[1]: set: -2: unknown option
Usage: set [-sabefhkmnprtuvxBCGH] [-A name] [-o[option]] [arg ...]
$ eval set -A ary -- $out
$ echo "${ary[@]}"       
-1/2 -B A C
```

The error message shows that it's valid to put further options after `-A name`, so you have to use `--` to mark the end of options.

I still think using `eval` is a horrible way to remove quotes.